# How do I override initWithContentRect in MacRuby?

Tags: ruby, cocoa, macruby

I want to override initWithContentRect on a subclassed NSWindow, as I've seen done in Obj-C, in order to create a borderless window from a nib.

If I try this:

```
class GroupWindow < NSWindow
def initWithContentRect(contentRect, styleMask:windowStyle, backing:bufferingType, defer:deferCreation)
    super.initWithContentRect(
        contentRect,
        styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask,
        backing:bufferiMacngType,
        defer:deferCreation)
end
end
```

Then it terminates with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

If I try this:

```
    def initWithContentRect(contentRect, styleMask:windowStyle, backing:bufferingType, defer:deferCreation)
    super(
        contentRect,
        styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask,
        backing:bufferingType,
        defer:deferCreation)
end
```

Then it just exits with return code 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

super(contentRect, NSBorderlessWindowMask, bufferingType, deferCreation)